# efficient way of computing partition and product of polynomial (python, sympy)

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a efficient way to computer partition and product of polynomial related questions?
Example: Find the number of ways of changing a hundred dollar bill into bills of smaller denominations, namely 1, 5, 10, 20, 50 dollar bills.

I was only able to derive the solution by manually inputting all the terms as such:

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

sympy.expand((1 + x**50 + x**100)*
             
(1 + x**20 + x**40 + x**60 + x**80 + x**100)*
             
(1 + x**10 + x**20 + x**30 + x**40 + x**50 + x**60 + x**70 + x**80 + x**90 + x**100)*
             
(1 + x**5 + x**10 + x**15 + x**20 + x**25 + x**30 + x**35 + x**40 + x**45 + x**50 +
x**55 + x**60 + x**65 + x**70 + x**75 + x**80 + x**85 + x**90 + x**95 + x**100))
```

output:
[image]

Next manually adding all the coefficients with exponents <=100

```
print(1+1+2+2+4+4+6+6+9+9+13+13+18+18+24+24+31+31+39+39+49)
```

Technically, there are two parts:
first to automate the exponents of each block of summation to increase according to it's related value after each summation.
example:(1 + x^20 + x^40 + x^60 + x^80 + x^100) has the exponents increase by 20 after every summation. I was thinking of using loops, however, can't figure out how to do multiple exponents with different conditions.

second: is summing the output of the coefficients with exponents <=100

Kindly advise. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make some progress in terms of using loops if you think about how you would create values for one of the bills. For the 50 you want multiples of 50 up to the value 100. How many multiples of 50 are in 100?

```
>>> nmul = 100//50
>>> [i*50 for i in range(nmul+1)]
[0, 50, 100]
```

Now do the same for the other bills of interest and identify what is varying each time -- and handle that with a loop variable, hint: `for bill in (5,10,20,50):...` Once you have a loop doing what you want, you will probably want to collect the results rather than print them to the screen.

Once you have the exponents you can use them to create the factors of the polynomial. And after you multiply them together you can get their coefficients in a dictionary like:

```
>>> from sympy import Poly
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> p = Poly((1+x**2+x**4+x**8)*(1+x**4+x**8))
>>> dict(p.as_expr().as_coefficients_dict())
{1: 1, x**2: 1, x**6: 1, x**10: 1, x**16: 1, x**4: 2, x**12: 2, x**8: 3}
>>> [_[i] for i in _ if i==1 or i.exp <= 8]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

But there is a delightfully simple way to do this using the generating function (a nice reflection on this is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/245615/122921)).

```
>>> from sympy.polys.ring_series import rs_pow
>>> from sympy.polys.rings import ring
>>> from sympy import ZZ
>>> R, x = ring('x', ZZ)
>>> target = 100
>>> den = rprod([1-x**i for i in (1,5,10,20,50)])
```

The inverse of `den` is a polynomial whose coefficient of `x**S` gives the number of ways that `S` can be made from the indicated "bills" 1,5,.... Given an infinite supply, this inverse must have infinite terms. But we are only interested in the ways to make 100. So we only need to compute the inverse to that many terms and then check the coefficient:

```
>>> ans = rs_pow(den,-1,x,target+1)  # calc 1/den up to x**target
>>> ans.coeff(x**target)
343
```

The [reference I gave](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/245615/122921) describes how to compute the coefficient for an arbitrarily large term without doing the whole expansion when all coins evenly divide the largest.

Comment: thank you for the answer and explanation. I'm working on how to "collect" and apply the exponents as you suggested. Will feedback shortly.